# how can i pass my repository to variable and pass it in a variable again in the same line?

Tags: c#

Hello guys can i ask how can i do this properly?

How can I pass my repository to PrintEntries and pass it in sMegaportsLog?
My error is when I passing my repository in `Print Entries`.

```
object PrintEntries= "";
string sMegaportsLog = "";

sMegaportsLog = PrintEntries.(new OutGateRepository().
LogMegaportHold(lblContainerNo.Text, sData, GUser));
```

Comment: the code which you shared does not make any sense. What error you are facing? You need to share more code and details and explain what issue you are facing.

Comment: Can you post the entire PrintEntries function here?

Comment: Try replacing `PrintEntries.(new OutGateRepository().` with `PrintEntries(new OutGateRepository());` :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As it is currently, this isn't valid C#. `PrintEntries.(` won't compile; there needs to be a method name after the `.`, but even then , `PrintEntries` is a string (or rather, it's declared as `object` but you've assigned a string to it), so I'm not sure what method you're trying to call. Perhaps if you explain in more detail what this code is supposed to do, we may be able to better understand how to help you.